# Enable next button on click first button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 5 buttons in row on click first button only second button should enable on click second button the third button should enable. till the 4th button.

Any one can suggest me for the implementation will be appreciated.

```
buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"3",@"4", nil];
```

// Cell for row index path added this code.

```
for (int buttonCount = 0; buttonCount<  [[buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]; buttonCount++)
{
    int buttonSpace = 10 * buttonCount + 10;
    cell.Button = [[CustomGoalButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonSpace + (buttonCount * 50),35, 50, 50)];
    cell.Button.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    [cell.Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.Button.buttonIndex = buttonCount;
    cell.Button.tag =  100 * (indexPath.row + 1)+ buttonCount;
    if (buttonCount == 0) {
        cell.Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    [cell.ScrollView addSubview:cell.Button];
}


// Button Action
    -(void)buttonAction:(CustomButton *)sender{
         UITableViewCell *cell = ( UITableViewCell *)[self. UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self. UITableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        if (sender.selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row) {
            sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            sender.tag = sender.tag+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share code you have written to do that?

Comment: are you used the concept in tableview or scrollview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i used in UITableView

Comment: use tag concept for each button

Comment: Show us your coding

Comment: Do you use custom cell?

Comment: @user3182143 Yes. and also custom button too which do have indexValue integer

Comment: @kiran Please check my answer.

Comment: How do you expect the result?

Comment: @user3182143 In sequence of row button, on click first button second button should enable, on click second button third button enable.  all clicked button will be disable mode.

Comment: If I click last button what will happen?

Comment: Kiran Check my answer.I created sample one for your question.It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this kind of functionality. I have sample code so you will get an idea how to do this-

[image]

Here is sample code-

```
buttonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"4",@"3",@"4", nil];

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return buttonArray.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    for (int buttonCount = 0; buttonCount<  [[buttonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]; buttonCount++)
    {
        int buttonSpace = 10 * buttonCount + 10;
        UIButton* Button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonSpace + (buttonCount * 50),35, 50, 50)];
        Button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        Button.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
        [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        Button.tag =  100 * (indexPath.row + 1)+ buttonCount;
        if (buttonCount == 0) {
            Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            Button.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        }
        else{
            Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            Button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        }

        [cell addSubview:Button];
    }

    return cell;

}
// Button Action
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender{

    UITableViewCell *cell = ( UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if ([cell viewWithTag:sender.tag+1]==nil) {

        UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:100 * (indexPath.row + 1)+ 0];

        btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

        btn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        sender.userInteractionEnabled=false;

        sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    }else{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:sender.tag+1];

    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    btn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    sender.userInteractionEnabled=false;

    sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    }

}
```

Note: If you don't want looping then remove if condtion i.e. `if ([cell viewWithTag:sender.tag+1]==nil)` in **buttonAction**, use only else part. Hope this will help you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a outlet collection of all the buttons. Make last 4 buttons disabled.

2) Create a oultet such that all the action should every button should call same method.

Below code will fix your requirement.

```
@IBAction func allButtonsTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let index = numberButtons.indexOf(sender as! UIButton)
    if numberButtons.count > index+1 {
        let button = numberButtons[index!+1]
        button.enabled = true
    }

}
```

EDIT: OBJC code

```
-(void) allButtonsTapped:(id)sender {
    int index = [numberButtons indexOfObject:((UIButton *)sender)]
    if numberButtons.count > index+1 {
        UIButton *button = numberButtons.objectAtIndex(index+1)
        button.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is about Objective-c and in swift dear..

Comment: @Dev.RK okay, looks like you are right.
I will change the code to ObjC for you.
But you get the logic behind the code.

Comment: @RiosK changed the answer to objc. Let me know if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Tag your button like this

```
button1.tag = 1
button2.tag = 2
button3.tag = 3
button4.tag = 4
```

Add click event of all four button as "**buttonClicked**".

I assume that you have properties of your four buttons in table view cell. So add following code when any button is tapped.

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
CGPoint center= sender.center;
CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.tabelView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tabelView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];

UITableViewCell *cell = [_tabelView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (sender.tag) {
    case 1:
    {
        [cell.btn1 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn2 setEnabled:YES];
        [cell.btn3 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn4 setEnabled:NO];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        [cell.btn1 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn2 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn3 setEnabled:YES];
        [cell.btn4 setEnabled:NO];
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        [cell.btn1 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn2 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn3 setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.btn4 setEnabled:YES];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Change above code according to your requirement. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @No madam its not i expected, but thanks for feedback.

Comment: @kiran then what you want?

Comment: @kiran As per your requirement "In sequence of row button, on click first button second button should enable, on click second button third button enable. all clicked button will be disable mode". above code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Exact answer for your question.I tried sample for you.It works perfectly.You can use same code and get the solution.

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrayTableData;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableviewCustomCellButton

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  arrayTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Asia",@"Europe",@"Atlantic",@"Africa",@"Antartica",nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return arrayTableData.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
     NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
     cell = nibs[0];
   }
   cell.labelData.text = [arrayTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   [cell.btnClick addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [cell.btnClick setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [cell.btnClick setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   cell.btnClick.tag = indexPath.row;

   return cell;
}

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
  UIButton *btnNext = sender;
  int buttonTag = (int)sender.tag;
  NSLog(@"The buttonTag is - %d",buttonTag);
  buttonTag = buttonTag+1;
  NSIndexPath *indexPath;
  CustomCell *cellBut;
  if(buttonTag < arrayTableData.count)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<arrayTableData.count;i++)
    {
          if(buttonTag == i)
          {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:buttonTag inSection:0];
            cellBut = (CustomCell *)[tableviewCustomCellButton cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            btnNext = (UIButton*)[cellBut viewWithTag:buttonTag];
            btnNext.selected = YES;
          }
          else
          {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            cellBut = (CustomCell *)[tableviewCustomCellButton cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            btnNext = (UIButton*)[cellBut viewWithTag:i];
            btnNext.selected = NO;
          }
       }
  }
  else
  {
    for(int i=0;i<arrayTableData.count;i++)
    {
        if(buttonTag == 5)
        {
            buttonTag = buttonTag - (int)[arrayTableData count];
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:buttonTag inSection:0];
            cellBut = (CustomCell *)[tableviewCustomCellButton cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            btnNext = (UIButton*)[cellBut viewWithTag:buttonTag];
            btnNext.selected = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            cellBut = (CustomCell *)[tableviewCustomCellButton cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            btnNext = (UIButton*)[cellBut viewWithTag:i];
            btnNext.selected = NO;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

In above code I use the Custom Cell with Label and Button.If You Click the 1 button second button will be selected like same actions for other buttons.Check my answer.